# Codeblocks automatically closes on Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, code-blocks

I have codeblocks installed it is now randomly closing while im coding. It closes automatically. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have same problem few weeks ago, and solution was reinstalling codeblocks.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge codeblocks

sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```